# Why are only my large media queries working?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been adding media queries to make my site more responsive. The larger queries (min-width 1536px and min-width 1224px) work fine. However, when I apply the styles to smaller sizes none of the styles show up at all. I don't understand why they won't, I know somethings might not fix with out adjusting sizes and positions but the colors aren't working which leads me to believe that I have done something wrong with the @media part itself.

http://www.codeply.com/go/z6EPsEzrOx

```
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Header */

header .img-responsive {
    padding-top: 2%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


/* Body */
#top {
    background-color: #FA7862;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#top h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#top h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}

#top h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

#top hr {
    line-height: 1em;
}

.info {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1% 2% 1% 2%;
    text-align: justify;
    border: solid grey 2px;
}

.connect {
    margin-left: 5%;
    color: white;
    width: 100;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

.connect p {
    margin-top: 5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.create {
    color: white;
    width: 100;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 12%;
}

.create p {
    margin-top: 7.5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.publish {
    color: white;
    width: 100;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 12%;
}

.publish p {
    margin-top: 7.5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Bottom */

body {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}

#bottom h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#mce-EMAIL
{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 40px;
}
input.button
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    background-color: #fa7862;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
}

#mc_embed_signup
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    left: 37.5%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40px;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Header */

header .img-responsive {
    padding-top: 2%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


/* Body */
#top {
    background-color: #FA7862;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#top h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#top h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}

#top h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

#top hr {
    line-height: 1em;
}

.info {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1% 2% 1% 2%;
    text-align: justify;
    border: solid grey 2px;
}

.connect {
    margin-left: 5%;
    color: white;
    width: 100;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

.connect p {
    margin-top: 5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.create {
    color: white;
    width: 100;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 12%;
}

.create p {
    margin-top: 7.5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.publish {
    color: white;
    width: 100;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 12%;
}

.publish p {
    margin-top: 7.5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Bottom */

body {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}

#bottom h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#mce-EMAIL
{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 40px;
}
input.button
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    background-color: #fa7862;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
}

#mc_embed_signup
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    left: 37.5%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40px;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2%;
}
}
```

Comment: You have set the min-width on every style, so there are no styles left when the width is to small.

Comment: Right but if I size the screen to like 1000px I still don't get any styles. But at 1300 it has all the styles.

Comment: You haven't define media queries for small devices. Your minimum width is 768px. There is no media query works for devices less than 768px

Comment: You are using device-width in your media queries instead of just max-width or min-width. The device-width of an iPhone 6 supposedly exceeds any external monitor's device-width you might be testing on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `min-width` and `max-width` instead of `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`.

Comment: **device width:** Describes the width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window). **width:** The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the width of the page box on a printer).

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to write your styles for a larger screen size, then adjust it with media queries for smaller screens. As your code stands, there's a gap between 1024 and 1224. So what I suggest is designing your page first at 1224 outside your media queries. Then use a media query for 1024, and a second one for 768. Likely you'll also need to target smaller sizes after that. Place each successively smaller size below the other, and use min-width:

```
//css code for large screen
//then:

@media screen and (min-width:1024px){//styles}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {//styles}

@media screen and (min-width:400px) {//styles}
```